# NHibernate Search FieldAttribute

Tags: lucene.net, nhibernate.search

I am not sure what are the parameters Index.Tokenized and Store actually meam, and how the value affect the index result? What is the difference between 2 properties below?

```
class A{
  [Field(Index.Tokenized, Store = Store.Yes)]
  public virtual string P1 {
    get;
    set;
  }

  [Field]
  public virtual string P2 {
    get;
    set;
  }
}
```

Thanks

Hardy

Answer (score 1):

Index.Tokenized means that the field will be tokenized.

Store.Yes means that the field will be stored in index.

Full explanation here : [Lucene indexing: Store and indexing modes explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650643/lucene-indexing-store-and-indexing-modes-explained)

```
[Field]
public virtual string P2 {
  get;
  set;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
[Field(Index.Tokenized, Store = Store.No)]
public virtual string P2 {
  get;
  set;
}
```