# How to read a document in lucene which is not stored but indexed

Tags: lucene

Hello i have  3 fields title,content,url and i created the index added some document

```
 Document doc = new Document();
  doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));
  doc.add(new TextField("content", title, Field.Store.YES));
  doc.add(new StringField("url", isbn, Field.Store.NO));
  w.addDocument(doc);
```

I can read the index using the index writer and iterate and receive the field title,content how can i receive the field url ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650643/lucene-indexing-store-and-indexing-modes-explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using "url" field but cannot get(display) it

for Example:

Field.Store.NO is suitable for id like fields which you need only to retrieve documents not for displaying

Answer (score 0):

Since you chose not to store it, I don't think you can. That's exactly what the "store" option is for (allowing you to retrieve more data than just the document id).

Answer (score 0):

> how can i receive the field url?

You can't. `Field.Store.NO` means Lucene takes this value and only uses it for indexing purposes so this document can be found if you query by matching `url`.